# How to use a form tag if the contents are organized in a table tag?

Tags: php, html

I tried using a table and found it fun because it makes it a lot easier for me to organize contents easily rather than just using plain divs;however, now my form won't work and I am not sure what is the problem.

HTML:

```
<?php
        include('connect.php');
    ?>

    <div class="signUpWrapper">
    <h1 class="contentMainHeader" style="text-align: center"> Create a new Admin </h1>
    <form method="post" name="registry" action="main index.php?page=thankyouPage">
    <table class="signUpTable">
        <tr style="height: 5em">
            <td>
            <div>
            <h1 class="userHeader">Name</h1>
            </div>
            <div>
            <input type="text" name="firstName" class="textbox" placeholder="First Name"/>&nbsp&nbsp
            <input type="text" name="lastName" class="textbox" placeholder="Last Name"/>
            </div>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr style="height: 5em">
            <td>
            <div>
            <h1 class="userHeader">Email</h1>
            </div>
            <div>
            <input type="text" name="email" class="textbox" placeholder="Email">&nbsp&nbsp
            <input type="text" name="email2" class="textbox" placeholder="Re-Enter Email"/>
            </div>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr style="height: 2em;">
            <td>
            <div>
            <input type="text" name="altEmail" class="textbox" placeholder="Alternate Email">&nbsp&nbsp
            </div>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr style="height: 5em">
            <td>
            <div>
            <h1 class="userHeader">Password</h1>
            </div>
            <div>
            <input type="text" name="password" class="textbox" placeholder="Password"/>&nbsp&nbsp
            <input type="text" name="password2" class="textbox" placeholder="Re-Enter Password"/>
            </div>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr style="height: 5em">
            <td>
            <div>
            <h1 class="userHeader">Birthday</h1>
            </div>
            <div>
            <select name="month" class="dropDown">
            <option selected>Select Month</option>
            <option> January </option>
            <option> February </option>
            <option> March </option>
            <option> April </option>
            <option> May </option>
            <option> June </option>
            <option> July </option>
            <option> August </option>
            <option> September </option>
            <option> October </option>
            <option> November </option>
            <option> December </option>
            </select>
            <input type="text" name="day" class="dateTextBox" placeholder="Day (dd)"/>&nbsp&nbsp
            <input type="text" name="year" class="dateTextBox" placeholder="Year (yyyy)"/>
            </div>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr style="height: 5em">
            <td>
            <div>
            <h1 class="userHeader">Gender</h1>
            </div>
            <select name="gender" class="dropDown">
            <option selected>Select Gender</option>
            <option> Male </option>
            <option> Female </option>
            </select>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr style="height: 5em">
            <td>
            <div>
            <h1 class="userHeader">Phone Number</h1>
            </div>
            <div>
            <input type="text" name="phoneNumber" class="textbox" placeholder="Phone Number">&nbsp&nbsp
            </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="height: 8em"><td>
        <input type="submit" value="Register" class="css_button">
        </td>
        </tr>


    </table>
    </form>
    </div>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

    #error_reporting(0);    

    $firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
    $lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $altEmail = $_POST['altEmail'];
    $gender = $_POST['gender'];
    $birthday = $_POST['month'] . "/" . $_POST['day'] . "/" . $_POST['year'];
    $phoneNumber = $_POST['phoneNumber'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];


    $sql = "INSERT INTO `admin` (`email`, `alternateEmail`, `firstName`, `lastName`, `password`, `DateOfBirth`, `Gender`, `phoneNumber`) VALUES ('$email', '$altEmail','$firstName', '$lastName', '$password', '$birthday', '$gender', '$phoneNumber')";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
?>
```

It redirects to a different php file containing the same PHP code, yet it isn't submitting any data to phpmyadmin.

Comment: form is not submitting????? what is error? where is form action?

Comment: There's no action in your form tag - is the PHP in the same file as the HTML form? Also, you are so, so wide open to SQL injection.

Comment: I guess you will get index not defined for the `$_POST`.

Comment: You didn't place the values for your select. And please close your `submit` with `/>`.

Comment: Do I still need an action in the form even if the php is on the same page?

Comment: You don't need if you are posting to the same page. But according to HTML5 specifications `action` must not be empty.

Comment: Thanks for that :D Now I know. Will give it a whirl to redirect to different page then.

Comment: @user3520494 Just added another answer with new info - check it out.

Comment: What makes you think the `table` element has anything to do with the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your form submits to itself, then an action attribute is not required. However, several values are missing from the form's `select` elements. For instance,

```
        <select name="month" class="dropDown">
        <option selected>Select Month</option>
        <option value="January"> January </option> <!--each option needs a value-->
```

All select options must have a value, or their result in the POST array will be empty. 
I'd recommend adding a name to your submit button:

```
<input type="submit" value="Register" name="Register" class="css_button" />
```

Which allows you to do a check to see if the form is submitted yet:

```
<?php

#error_reporting(0);    

if(isset($_POST['Register'])){

    $_POST = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST); //protect yourself from SQL injection...

    $country = $_POST['country'];
    $firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
    $lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
    //etc...
```

Finally, I believe that the INSERT is failing because **you are naming a `country` column without a corresponding `$country` variable to insert**. This leaves you with 9 columns named, and only 8 values to insert:

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO `admin` (`email`, `alternateEmail`, `firstName`, `lastName`, `password`, `DateOfBirth`, `country`, `Gender`, `phoneNumber`) VALUES ('$email', '$altEmail','$firstName', '$lastName', '$password', '$birthday', '$country', '$gender', '$phoneNumber')";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

I'm also not seeing a `mysql_connect` call anywhere, so I'm hoping you have a connection to the database somewhere?

Comment: Yes it is connected through the include connect.php way. In addition, I didn't add country to the code because it was pretty long and I didn't want to flood the question box. Thank you so much for your input! I will continue to investigate what is wrong with it.

Comment: So country *is* present in the real form?

Comment: Yes it is, I just removed it for the sake of not flooding the entire question box.

Comment: What do you think about the PHP syntax?

Comment: The problem isn't syntax, but coding practice - you can't just take a user's input and insert it directly into a database. That allows them to hack and or destroy your database quite easily. Take a look at [this now-legendary post on how to avoid that problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Otherwise the syntax seems to be fine. I believe the main problem was the MySQL syntax in the INSERT query. Did you try it with the new INSERT statement?

Comment: AH! Damn "," missing. Yeah it was the syntax. I understand the whole SQL injection problem and i will refer to that. I am just trying to learn some of the basics before moving onto doing that. Thank you so much for the warning. I totally appreciate this website helping me learn so much more from experiences developers/programmers like yourself!

Answer (score 0):

you forgot the action tag to specify the target php script to receive the data

```
<form method="post" name="registry" action="yourpage.php">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to submit values to Another page. You Should define **Form Action**

```
<form method="post" name="registry" action="Filepath">
```

Here is for details **[Form](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html)**, **[Action](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-action)**

If you don't define action of form or Leave action blank. Form submit to same page.

[<kbd>Example</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakmanwal/ZSLPP/1/)